# jersey 2.11 view all Resources

Tags: rest, jersey, restful-architecture

I am using the framework jersey 2.11 for practicing with REST webservice.
This is my simple class that works correctly:

```
@Path("/simple")
public class Service{

@GET
    @Path("method1")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getMethod1() {
    return "Hello_1";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("method2")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getMethod2() {
    return "Hello_2";
    }
}
```

I would like to have as a result a list of all my methods (Resources), for example:

my page index.html

```
<html>
 <body>
   <ul>`
    <li> getMethod1 </li>
    <li> getMethod2 </li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can see this example: [https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1][1]

I would like to get a list of all my resources.
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly you want do document all the resources in your project,if so you can use https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui or enunciate http://enunciate.codehaus.org/index.html.Or if you are just looking to create a html page then you can use the Application jersey class (https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.6/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) and the getClases method and then use reflection to figure all the public endpoints